# ProcessBuilder with multiple commands

Tags: java, linux, sh, processbuilder

I'd like to execute multiple commands with `ProcessBuilder`. I want to avoid using script files, only hardcoded strings in Java.

This is the current file that I'd like to execute.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -e /tmp/pipe ]
then
    rm /tmp/pipe
fi
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
tail -f /dev/null >/tmp/pipe & # keep pipe alive
cat /tmp/pipe | omxplayer $1 -r &
```

Now, this is my current code.

```
private static final String[][] commands =  {
                                                {"rm", "-f", "/tmp/airpi_pipe"},
                                                {"mkfifo", "/tmp/airpi_pipe"},
                                                {"tail", "-f", "/dev/null", ">", "/tmp/airpi_pipe"}
                                            };

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (String[] str : commands) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(str);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = pb.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        System.err.println("next one");
    }
}
```

Obviously, the `tail` command doesn't work in my `ProcessBuilder`. I haven't even tried with `cat /tmp/pipe | omxplayer $1 -r &`.

So, my question is, how could I manage to execute the content of my sh script with `ProcessBuilder`, but only with hardcoded commands (no script file), as I'm trying to do?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I had to use new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "<commands>"); to make it work!

Comment: Hint: How would you do the same task on the command line as a single line?

Comment: Remember you have to call the shell to get shell capabilities, otherwise the commands get run directly from Java.

Comment: new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", <command>); this code works like a charm, thanks!